# Is there any way bywhich, i can force browser not to prompt remember password box?

Tags: javascript, html

I am setting up a website, where users have to provide their PIN numbers for a actual transaction to happen. I have done HTML for the INPUT field to be TYPE=PASSWORD. But on submit, browser asks to save the password, which is the pin number. Is there any way that i can make browser not to ask for save password ?

Comment: Don't do that; you should allow users to save PINs too.

Comment: Not to ask and always save or never save then ?
To never save i found [this article](https://makandracards.com/makandra/34245-how-to-disable-auto-complete-on-login-forms)